# Creating UI for windows 8.1 metro apps using only c# without xaml

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-8.1

Is it possible for me create a page in windows 8.1 using purely c# code.. If yes how is it done?

I tried the following code which failed:

```
namespace App6
{
    class Login: Page
    {

        Grid grd;

        public Login()
        { 
            grd = new Grid();

            grd.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
            grd.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
            grd.Background = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255,255, 255, 217));
        }
    }
}
```

I then tried to navigate to this page using **this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Login))** from the mainpage but this throws an System.TypeLoadException saying that **could not find windows runtime type Windows.Foundation**

What is the proper way to create and navigate to a page created using only c#?

Comment: You could (XAML is based on .NET types), but my question would be: Why? In my opinion that's a really bad idea. You don't have Designer support, building animations is horror, changing the design at a later point in time is nearly impossible (depending on the complexity of your UI) etc.

Comment: I have a requirement where I have to deliver a xaml page as a part of a class library. But it does not include .xaml pages as a part of the .dll file. So I have to deliver the .xaml file seperately as a component which is not acceptable. I am assuming if I write UI in pure c# it will possible to include them in .dll without exposing any code to user.

Comment: You can add XAML pages into class libraries, you just have to create a WPF User Control library. Then it will be built into the dll and you'll be able to deliver it as a dll.

Comment: I tried create a UserControl library but still throws the XamlParseException... Its the same error as when using a normal xaml page in .dll.

Comment: Can u give me some link where it shown how to create an entire page class using only C#.. I managed to create the UI but am not able to perform navigation as the frame is null.